# React native: AsyncStorage returns Objects are not valid as a React child and garbage values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I've been looking for a solution for my problem here but haven't found anything that works.

Currently I've got a function to get an Array of objects from AsyncStorage.

```
const get = async (key) => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(prefix + key);
        const item = JSON.parse(value);

        console.log("From get" + JSON.stringify(item.value));
        return item.value;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error" + error);
    }
};
```

This is what I get in the `console.log`

`From get[{"id":1,"name":"Push Up","sets":[{"reps":"","weight":""}]},{"id":2,"name":"Pull Up","sets":[{"reps":"","weight":""}]},{"id":3,"name":"Bicep Curl","sets":[{"reps":"","weight":""}]}`]

I'm trying to get the values from another component like this

```
const getCacheData = (item) => {
    const data = cache.get(item.toString());
    console.log("Get Cache Data" + JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

`Console.log` prints `Get Cache Data{"_U":0,"_V":0,"_W":null,"_X":null}`

If I make getCache into an `async` function and `await cache.get()`, then I get the following error -

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here? It works as I want it to in the `get()` function but it doesn't work as expected from another function.

Thanks for looking into this!!

Comment: Are you rendering the result of `getCacheData` in your component?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the object on a button click.

onPress={getCacheData}